# How can I have `menu-bar--display-line-numbers-mode-relative` run in all modes?

Tags: line-numbers

I see there is a `menu-bar--display-line-numbers-mode-relative` function that turns on relative line numbering. Is there a way I can run this in every buffer (basically turn this on everywhere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the Customization Interface

Use Customization Interface to go to the `display-line-numbers` group (`M-x customize-group RET display-line-numbers RET`) and set:

1. `display-line-numbers-type` to `'relative`; and
2. `global-display-line-number-mode` to `t`.

#### Manually

Add

```lisp
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
```

to your init file.